# rename keyspace and columnfamily in cassandra 1.2

Tags: cassandra, rename, cql3

How to rename keyspace and columnfamily in cassandra 1.2? I know that cassandra-cli rename api is no longer supported - [How to rename keyspace in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649104/how-to-rename-keyspace-in-cassandra). Maybe there are some api in CQL3? Or some api for creating new columnfamily and coping all data from old to new columnfamily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming is disabled internally, not just within the thrift API.  So there isn't a CQL command to do it either.

However, there is a manual process which is described here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1585

Comment: Link is broken.  Could you either fix, or provide the steps here?

Answer (score 3):

For rename only a column family also you can follow the next instructions:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201201.mbox/%3C4EF306AC-98D5-45BE-A29C-B68187FBA9C9@thelastpickle.com%3E

Basically is create the new CF, copy the SStables from the old column family to the one renaming the files.