# Is there a way to rename a keyspace while cloning a cluster using OpsCenter?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I am working on a project which requires me to clone an existing cassandra cluster using OpsCenter. But at the same time I want to rename the keyspace that I want to clone. Is there a way to do that? I have gone through the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/online_help/services/opscBackupCloneCluster.html). But not able to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated . Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Also renaming keyspace/column family may lead to problems like race condition.please go through the link [rename-keyspace-and-columnfamily.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649104/how-to-rename-keyspace-in-cassandra)

Though you can find workaround for these [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759667/rename-keyspace-and-columnfamily-in-cassandra-1-2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i ended up creating a cluster and then using [cassandradump](https://github.com/gianlucaborello/cassandradump) to export data from the old cluster. After that Created cql files and did a grep and sed to change the keyspace names

Answer (score 0):

There was no direct way to do this. So finally ended up with a roundabout solution.

1. Created a new cluster.
2. Used [cassandradump](https://github.com/gianlucaborello/cassandradump) to export data from the old cluster keyspace.
3. Created a keyspace with a new name in the new cluster
4. Modified the exported cql files using sed to replace the old keyspace names with the new keyspace names.
5. Imported the cql files to the new cluster using 'SOURCE' CQL command