# Create a duplicate of an existing Keyspace in Cassandra (with a new name)

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra

I have a keyspace in a `Cassandra` database. It contains a number of tables and these tables contain data. For TDD purpose, I need to create an exact copy of the keyspace. I guess it is a single line of code to execute in python. Any ideas?

Comment: Copy only schema ?  With different keyspace name ?

Comment: No copy its tables and their values too. Needed for testing.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/gianlucaborello/cassandradump

Comment: I am not aware of such command. What it's your use case? You plan to have the data on the same cluster or on a different one?

Comment: Same cluster...

Comment: Is it a production cluster? If so, I would not recommend to duplicate your data for testing on the same cluster. Because of space, performance. Anyway. One way you could do it it's to create a indetical keyspace with a different name and the tables that you need to replicate. Then copy the keyspace folder to some other location and then use sstableloader to stream the data into the new keyspace and table.

Comment: Okay. No command to do it directly. I see. No it's not a prod cluster.

Comment: @AbhisekRoy is my solution helping you and put it as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to "copy" a keyspace, in the same cluster? There is no build in CQLSH command to achieve that, yet it's actually simple. Let's assume your source keyspace is keyspace_source, and your dest keyspace is keyspace_dest

a. extract the schema of your keyspace:

```
cqlsh -e "DESCRIBE KEYSPACE keyspace_source" > keyspace_source.txt
```

b. edit keyspace_source.txt to change the name of the keyspace to keyspace_dest

c. apply the schema with:

```
cqlsh -f 'keyspace_source.txt'
```

d. on each node, create a snapshot (at the same time) with

```
nodetool snapshot -t copy keyspace_source
```

At this exact moment, any write that goes to a table of keyspace_source will not be part of keyspace_dest. The snapshot directory will be named copy, in this example

e. On each nodes, move all the snapshot files of the tables to the new keyspace (repeat for each table in the keyspace):

```
mv /var/lib/cassandra/data/data/keyspace_source/table_source1-*/snapshot/copy/* /var/lib/cassandra/data/data/keyspace_dest/table_dest1-*/
```

f. Finally, instruct cassandra to refresh the SSTables with (repeat for each table in the keyspace):

```
nodetool refresh keyspace_dest table_dest1
```

Optionally, you might want to repair the keyspace keyspace_dest. That's just because it is impossible to run a snapshot at an exact same time on all the nodes.

Comment: I should mention, watch out for the disk usage. At first, there won't be any difference as you are using hard links. But over time, the tables in your two keyspaces will have different compaction path, and you will double the disk usage related to your keyspace.

Answer (score 1):

To put what @christophe-schmitz describes into a shell script I present this sample I just did for my Keyspace running on C* 3.11:

You will need ssh keys setup from the host you run the shell script to each of your server C* nodes, ex:

bash cloneKeyspace.sh root server1 server1,server2,server3,server4,server5,server6 keyspace_src keyspace_dest

```
#!/bin/bash
cloneKeyspace()
{
    local username="${1}"
    local start_host="${2}"
    local hostnames="${3}"
    local keyspace_source="${4}"
    local keyspace_destination="${5}"

    if ssh ${username}@${start_host} "echo 2>&1"; then
     ssh ${username}@${start_host} "cqlsh -e 'DESCRIBE KEYSPACE ${keyspace_source}' > ${keyspace_source}.txt"
     ssh ${username}@${start_host} "sed -i 's/${keyspace_source}/${keyspace_destination}/g' ${keyspace_source}.txt"
     ssh ${username}@${start_host} "cqlsh -f '${keyspace_source}.txt'"
     ssh ${username}@${start_host} "rm ${keyspace_source}.txt"      
     echo "Success on Keyspace Schema clone: "${start_host}
    else
      echo "Failed on Keyspace Schema clone: "${start_host}
    fi

    
    for hostname in $(echo $hostnames | sed "s/,/ /g")
    do
       if ssh ${username}@${hostname} "echo 2>&1"; then
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool snapshot -t copy ${keyspace_source}"
        echo "Success on Cassandra snapshot: "${hostname} ${keyspace_source}
        
        sleep 20
        
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/acls-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/acls-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/apis-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/apis-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/ca_certificates-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/ca_certificates-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/certificates-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/certificates-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/cluster_events-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/cluster_events-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/consumers-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/consumers-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/jwt_secrets-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/jwt_secrets-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/keyauth_credentials-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/keyauth_credentials-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/locks-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/locks-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/oauth2_authorization_codes-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/oauth2_authorization_codes-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/oauth2_credentials-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/oauth2_credentials-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/oauth2_tokens-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/oauth2_tokens-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/plugins-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/plugins-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/ratelimiting_metrics-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/ratelimiting_metrics-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/routes-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/routes-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/schema_meta-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/schema_meta-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/services-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/services-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/snis-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/snis-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/tags-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/tags-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/targets-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/targets-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/upstreams-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/upstreams-*/"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "mv /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_source}/workspaces-*/snapshots/copy/* /data/cassandra/data/${keyspace_destination}/workspaces-*/"
        
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool clearsnapshot -t copy"
        
        echo "Success on Cassandra mv of snapshot files to destination: "${keyspace_destination}
        
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} ratelimiting_metrics"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} oauth2_tokens"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} locks"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} snis"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} plugins"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} targets"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} consumers"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} upstreams"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} schema_meta"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} tags"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} acls"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} cluster_events"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} workspaces"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} jwt_secrets"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} apis"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} keyauth_credentials"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} oauth2_credentials"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} certificates"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} services"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} ca_certificates"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} oauth2_authorization_codes"
        ssh ${username}@${hostname} "nodetool refresh ${keyspace_destination} routes"
        
        echo "Success on Cassandra nodetool refresh on destination keyspace: "${keyspace_destination}
       else
        echo "Failed on Cassandra snapshot: "${hostname}
       fi
    done
    
    if ssh ${username}@${start_host} "echo 2>&1"; then
     ssh ${username}@${start_host} "nodetool repair -full ${keyspace_destination}"
     echo "Success on Keyspace repair: "${start_host} ${keyspace_destination}
    else
     echo "Failed on Keyspace repair : "${start_host} ${keyspace_destination}
    fi
    
    echo "Script processing completed!"
}

cloneKeyspace "${1}" "${2}" "${3}" "${4}" "${5}"
```

This could be improved with some regex magic to get the tables and not hardcode mv and refresh them but for a quick and dirty it worked for me

Comment: Thanks, @Jeremy but I needed the code in Python as mentioned at the top.

Comment: Yep saw that ask, but saw this post had no code just guidance since 2018, someone can adapt it to python if they wanted but wanted to give the community something to takeaway to use if they stumble here like I did. shell scripting can be used in any *nix environment which keeps things flexible.